# Find the outermost peak of a function to calculate the cutoff radius for pseudopotential calculation

Tags: pseudopotentials, optimization

## Problem presentation

The problem mentioned in this [paper about norm conserving potentials](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.43.1494). I cite `we choose a cutoff radius, typically 0.5 to 1.0 times the radius of the outermost peak of [the valence wavefunction]`.

I think this problem can be written as the following optimization problem:

Find $x$ such that:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\max_{x\in \mathcal{D}}{f(x)}\\
\max_{x\in \mathcal{D}}{x}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
where $f$ is the function I want to minimize and $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{R}⁺$ the definition domain of $x$. $f$ is a sum of contracted primitive gaussians (also a linear combination of gaussians).

**How is the cutoff radius usually solved for?**

## Context

I want to follow the procedure mentionned in the paper to generate norm-conserving pseudo-potentials for a carbon atom.

Comment: If you want to minimize f, and f is a linear combination of gaussians, than the answer is x->infty. Is it possible you mean to minimize the error in the norm of f(x)?

Comment: The function f is of the form $\sum_i c_i e^{-\alpha_i |x - x_i|²}$, where $c_i \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\alpha_i>0$. So $x = +\infty$ is not necessary the solution. But I edited my question to replace the min by max since I want "peaks".

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you are looking for. Are you trying to locate the outermost peak? what is outermost in reference to, the center of mass? Are you trying to minimize the error when choosing a cutoff? Are you trying to minimize f(x) as you state?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for the outermost peak. So $\forall x>x_{cutoff}, f'(x)<0$ and $f(x_{cutoff}) < f(x)$